# How do you pass the parent entity to a form in Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

Suppose I have two entities: a `post` and a `comment`. Each `post` can have many `comments`. Now, suppose I have a comment form. It is supposed to take user input and store it in the database.

Simple stuff. At least, it should be, but I can't get it to work.

**How do I refer to the post (parent) when creating the comment (child)?** I tried manually passing the `post_id` to the comment form as a hidden field, but received an error complaining about how the post ID is a string.

```
Expected argument of type "App\Entity\Post or null", "string" given.
```

---

### Here is my code so far. Can someone nudge me into the right direction?

**CommentType.php**

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $post_id = $options['post_id'];

    $builder->add('content', TextareaType::class, [
        'constraints' => [
            new Assert\NotBlank(['message' => 'Your comment cannot be blank.']),
            new Assert\Length([
                'min'        => 10,
                'minMessage' => 'Your comment must be at least {{ limit }} characters long.',
            ]),
        ],
    ])->add('post', HiddenType::class, ['data' => $post_id]);
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'data_class' => Comment::class,
        'post_id' => NULL,
    ]);
}
```

---

**PostController.php** (this is where the comment form appears)

```
// Generate the comment form.
$comment = new Comment();
$form = $this->createForm(CommentType::class, $comment, [
    'action' => $this->generateUrl('new_comment'),
    'post_id'   => $post_id,
]);
```

---

**CommentController.php**

```
/**
 * @param Request $request
 * @Route("/comment/new", name="new_comment")
 * @return
 */
public function new(Request $request, UserInterface $user)
{
    // 1) Build the form
    $comment = new Comment();
    $form = $this->createForm(CommentType::class, $comment);

    // 2) Handle the submit (will only happen on POST)
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid())
    {
        // 3) Save the comment!
        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $entityManager->persist($comment);
        $entityManager->flush();
    }

    return $this->redirectToRoute('homepage');
}
```

---

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: As mentioned in error message you need to pass the entity object of your post_id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works for me:

**CommentController.php**

As suggested by flint above, you just need to pass the actual Post entity, not just the id. Then if you have this error `"Unable to guess how to get a Doctrine instance from the request information for parameter "post"` this is because you need to add the **post** slug in the path of the **new_comment** route. The ParamConverter is called implicitly and it need this slug **{post}** with the same name as the name you used for the **post** parameter in the function.

```
/**
 * @param Request $request
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse
 * @Route("/comment/new/{post}", name="new_comment")
 */
public function new(Request $request, Post $post)
{
    $comment = new Comment();
    $comment->setPost($post); //where $post is instance of App\Entity\Post
    $form = $this->createForm(CommentType::class, $comment);

    // 2) Handle the submit (will only happen on POST)
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid())
    {
        // 3) Save the comment!
        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $entityManager->persist($comment);
        $entityManager->flush();
    }

    return $this->redirectToRoute('homepage');
}
```

**PostController.php**

```
/**
 * @Route("/post/{id}", name="get_post")
 */
public function getPostAction(Post $post)

{
    // Generate the comment form.
    $comment = new Comment();
    $form = $this->createForm(CommentType::class, $comment, [
        'action' => $this->generateUrl('new_comment', ['post' => $post->getId()]),
    ]);

    return $this->render('listeArticles.html.twig', [
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ]);

 }
```

**CommentType.php**

```
class CommentType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        //don't need to set the $post here

        $builder
            ->add('content', TextareaType::class, [
            'constraints' => [
                new Assert\NotBlank(['message' => 'Your comment cannot be blank.']),
                new Assert\Length([
                    'min'        => 10,
                    'minMessage' => 'Your comment must be at least {{ limit }} characters long.',
                ]),
            ],
        ])
        ->add('submit', SubmitType::class);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Comment::class
        ]);
    }
}
```

With this you don't need to remove the Doctrine relationship between the two tables and manually set an ID.

Answer (score 4):

You just need to pass the actual `Post` entity, not just the id. Try this:

**CommentController.php**

```
public function new(Request $request, UserInterface $user, Post $post)
{
    // 1) Build the form
    $comment = new Comment();
    $comment->setPost($post); //where $post is instance of App\Entity\Post
    $form = $this->createForm(CommentType::class, $comment);

    // 2) Handle the submit (will only happen on POST)
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid())
    {
        // 3) Save the comment!
        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $entityManager->persist($comment);
        $entityManager->flush();
    }

    return $this->redirectToRoute('homepage');
}
```

**CommentType**

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    //don't need to set the $post here

    $builder->add('content', TextareaType::class, [
        'constraints' => [
            new Assert\NotBlank(['message' => 'Your comment cannot be blank.']),
            new Assert\Length([
                'min'        => 10,
                'minMessage' => 'Your comment must be at least {{ limit }} characters long.',
            ]),
        ],
    ]);
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'data_class' => Comment::class
         //don't need the default here either
     ]);
}
```

**Comment Entity**

```
class Comment 
{
  /** 
  * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Post")
  */
  private $post;

  //other vars

  public function setPost(\App\Entity\Post $post): void
  {
    $this->post = $post;
  }

  public function getPost(): \App\Entity\Post 
  {
     return $this->post;
  }

  //other functions
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. However, this does not work. `$post_id` is undefined in CommentType, and if I define it as a `Post` rather than an ID (string/int), I get a type conversion error.

Comment: Also, I do not have a `PostInterface`, unless there is something happening behind the scenes there that I do not understand.

Comment: Using an interface is best practice but you don't have to, you can typehint the entity. I've amended my answer to show the comment class as well.

See more here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/associations.html

Comment: Thank you, but my comment entity is already set up this way. The issue lies (I believe) in this line: `->add('post', HiddenType::class, ['data' => $post_id]);`. $post_id does not exist.

Comment: You don't need that line, I've corrected the answer. You are setting the post with $comment->setPost($post);

Comment: Thanks for all of your help. However, it's *still* not working. I get this error: `"Unable to guess how to get a Doctrine instance from the request information for parameter "post".` If I remove the $post parameter and instead manually create a Post object, I get this error instead: `A new entity was found through the relationship 'App\Entity\Comment#post' that was not configured to cascade persist operations for entity [...]`.

Comment: At this point, I may just remove the Doctrine relationship between the two tables and manually set an ID. I'd rather learn how to do this properly though.

Answer (score 0):

Dont put in to form field,
for exampled

```
public function new(Request $request, UserInterface $user)
{
    // 1) Build the form
    $comment = new Comment();
    $form = $this->createForm(CommentType::class, $comment);

    // 2) Handle the submit (will only happen on POST)
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid())
    {
        comment->setPostId($post_id)
        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $entityManager->persist($comment);
        $entityManager->flush();
    }

    return $this->redirectToRoute('homepage');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message says it all:

```
Expected argument of type "App\Entity\Post or null", "string" given.
```

If you go to your comment Entity (App\Entity\Comment) you'll see that your class refers to the parent post as a Post Class (App\Entity\Post) and not as a "post_id".

It is the ORM (doctrine in this case) who does the link in your physical database and your Entity classes and add a post_id field in your table.

This is the what ORM (Object Relational Model) is for. You should no more consider Post and Comment as Sql tables but as Classes (OOP).

Thus is I want to add a comment related to someParent I should do something like:

```
$comment = new Comment();
$comment->setPost($post);
```

Where $post is an instance of the class Post.